# Polish letters don't work in MZ 320 CPCL

Tags: java, unicode, zebra-printers

I downloaded Times New Roman font to my Zebra printer and when I click "Example printout" (sorry for bad translation) it prints polish letters, but when I'm using CPCL Command it doesn't work.

Example of my code:

```
"! 0 200 200 250 1\r\n"
+ "ON-FEED IGNORE\r\n"
+ "CENTER\r\n"
+ "ML 40\r\n" + "T TIMESNEW.CPF 0 0 20\r\n"
//Date doesn't work on this font, dunno why
+ "TEST !<DATE\r\n"
+ "ŁŃŚĆŻŹĆ\r\n" //(Polish letters)
+ "0123456789\r\n"
+ "ENDML\r\n"
+ "PRINT\r\n";
```

Comment: Might be a Unicode issue. What happens? Are the Polish letters just blank in the output? Is there an error message?

Comment: I had a lot of question marks instead of text, but I prepared a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is more simply than I thought.

We must declare a byte array, then we must do something like this:

```
ByteArray = PrintedText.getBytes(Charset.forName("CP1250"));
```

That's our result.

I found it [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601937/zebra-printer-serbian-latin-characters)